# Nilradical is always maximal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

The nilradical ideal of a commutative ring $R$ is the ideal of its nilpotents. It seems to me this ideal is always maximal, since if it's properly contained in another proper ideal $I$, then $I$ contains an invertible element and hence is the whole ring. Is this correct?

Comment: "then $I$ contains an invertible element". Not true. There could be zero divisors that are not nilpotent that $I$ could contain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take $R=\mathbb Z$. The nilradical is $\{0\}$, which is far from maximal.